# When Instantiated the gameobjects appear as Clones.Is there any way to identify each clones?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Consider a cube.Initially  the cube is converted to prefabs by dragging into the project window and deleted from the hierarchy.Now this prefab is getting Instantiated.So when it gets instantiated a couple of times, all the instantiated gameobjects will have the name **Cube(Clone)**.Is there a way to identify these clones like any unique features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

several ways. clicking them in the inspector will show them in the scene view and vice versa, but you could also do it via a script to increment some sort of ID, this method will go in place of your instantiation.

```
int id = 0;

                for ( int i = 0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    GameObject yourob = Instantiate(obj) as GameObject;
                    yourob.gameObject.name = "Object " + id;
                    id++;
                }
```

this will get rid of the clone name convention and leave you with

`Object 0` - `Object 4`

*note:* you can change the string `Object` to whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.

**Example:**

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject myPrefab;

    void Start()
    {
         GameObject g = null;
         for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {
             g = GameObject.Instantiate(myPrefab);
             g.name = "MyPrefab_" + (i+i);
         }
    }
}
```

This should instantiate 5 game objects named:

- MyPrefab_1
- MyPrefab_2
- MyPrefab_3
- MyPrefab_4
- MyPrefab_5

Comment: thats pretty close to my answer there @Chawy. functional and clean though, good answer.

Comment: Thanks @PrinceOfRavens, just noticed your answer right after I click the post button haha. Yup yup, we do have a similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to identify your objects through something else than the name directly, you can always add a field or property to these objects and display it in the editor associated (or the default one.)

That value would be populated by the constructor if auto-generated, or the Clone method if you want to have a control over it.